# Insert multiple string before paragraph tag

Tags: php, string

I would like to insert string before every paragraph until the end of content.
How to that not always inserting "Copyright A"? and reset to the beginning again when peak the limit "Copyright C"

```
$text = array('Coypright A', 'Coypright B', 'Coypright C');
$limit = '3';

for ( $x = 0; $x < $limit; $x++ ){
  $str = str_replace("<p>", "$text[0]<p>", get_the_content());
}
echo $str;
```

Comment: Using regex to parse valid html can lead to trouble because regex is tag-ignorant; in other words it doesn't know the difference between a tag and text that looks like a tag.  A DOM parser may be called for here.  Do you really want untagged text before your `<p>`?

Comment: ... regex or str_replace for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seeking a simple solution, regex can be avoided because your targeted opening p tag is a static string.

But really, I recommend a more robust solution leveraging domdocument in the long run.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/J1tGq))

```
$text = array('Copyright A', 'Copyright B', 'Copyright C');
$limit = 3;
$content = '<p>Paragraph1</p>
<p>Paragraph2</p>
<p>Paragraph3</p>
<p>Paragraph4</p>
<p>Paragraph5</p>
';
$target = '<p>';
$ptags = explode($target, $content);
$new_content = array_shift($ptags);
foreach ($ptags as $i => $p) {
    $new_content .= $text[$i % $limit] . $target . $p;
}
var_export($new_content);
```

Output:

```
'Copyright A<p>Paragraph1</p>
Copyright B<p>Paragraph2</p>
Copyright C<p>Paragraph3</p>
Copyright A<p>Paragraph4</p>
Copyright B<p>Paragraph5</p>
'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace_callback` to do what you want. In this example code, the callback iterates through the values in `$text` in order, looping when we reach `$limit` (using `$i = ($i + 1) % $limit;`). Those values are then prepended to any `<p>` found in the text:

```
$text = array('Copyright A', 'Copyright B', 'Copyright C');
$limit = 3;
$content = '<p>Paragraph1</p>
<p>Paragraph2</p>
<p>Paragraph3</p>
<p>Paragraph4</p>
<p>Paragraph5</p>
';
echo preg_replace_callback('/<p>/', 
    function ($m) use ($text, $limit) { 
        static $i = -1; 
        $i = ($i + 1) % $limit; 
        return $text[$i] . $m[0]; 
    }, $content);
```

Output:

```
Copyright A<p>Paragraph1</p> 
Copyright B<p>Paragraph2</p> 
Copyright C<p>Paragraph3</p> 
Copyright A<p>Paragraph4</p> 
Copyright B<p>Paragraph5</p>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/t3IU2)

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate `$limit` times; in this case it will only do the loop 3 times. You need to iterate the number of `<p>` tags times. With the code posted, there is no way to know how many p tags there are.  To cycle through the "copyright"s use the modulo `%` operator.

In pseudo-ish-code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < "number of p tags"; $i++) {
$str = str_replace("<p>", "$text[$i % $limit]<p>", get_the_content());
}
```

Or a `while` loop. Bottom line: you need to keep track of how many `<p>` you have processed to know which `$text` to "assign".